# number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length in R

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:(cutoff_size-1)){
if (work$obs<i){
work$group[i]<-0 }
else { work$group[i]<-1 } }

> work
     size event   time  obs group
1    0.0     1   7.213    1     1
2    0.2     0 103.000    2     0
3    0.3     0 156.000    3     0
20  19.0     1   3.934   73     1

> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In work$group[i] = rep(c(0, 1), c(i - 1, cutoff_size -  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I want to make group[1], group[2], ... variable like triangular matrix but it doesn't work. My for loop R code makes only one group variable.

How can I solve this?

I want to make my data set like this:

```
size event    time obs  group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5
0    1  7.213   1   1   0   0   0   0
0.2  0  103     2   1   1   0   0   0
0.3  0  156     3   1   1   1   0   0
0.4  0  125     4   1   1   1   1   0
0.5  2  98      5   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: I think that the part `if (work$obs<i){` doesn't look right. Maybe you wanted to type `if (work$obs[i]<i){` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to accomplish. If you just want threshold-based separation of groups, use this:

```
work$group=ifelse(work$obs<cutoff_size,0,1)
work
   size event    time obs group
1   0.0     1   7.213   1     0
2   0.2     0 103.000   2     0
3   0.3     0 156.000   3     0
20 19.0     1   3.934  73     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but it makes only one group. I want group1 will be 1,1,1,1 and group2 will be 0,1,1,1 like this.

Comment: Do you want to create new columns with group markers? Please show us example of your desired result.